# Replace motherboard capacitor with lower capacitance?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, motherboard

Is it possible and safe to replace a motherboard capacitor of 1800uF, 6.3V with a capacitor of slightly lower capacitance 1500uF and the same voltage 6.3V?

My motherboard does work, but it tends to drive the computer to an accidental turn off after 5 to 10 minutes of operation. Do I understand correctly, that the capacitors with -20% of capacitance should work, but the overall motherboard operation will not be reliable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible given the necessary skills and tools. Yes, it's safe. The only rating that matters for safety is the rated voltage: if you put a higher voltage than the maximum you might see your cap explode.

The question is: will it work? Probably yes, that cap is filtering some 3.3V going around your mother board, there must be a ton of them. Will it work *reliably*? Nope. It was that big for a reason. And I'd dare to guess that your replacement part is of lower quality than the original, higher ESR, lower precision... Moreover, yout mobo won't work again because you substitute a dead cap: it died for a reason, now that's something anybody is unlikely to find out.

Comment: How can you say with confidence that it was filtering 3.3V? And what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: "probably" is not really "with confidence". It will be an educated guess that that's what this sort of cap is usually used for. 3.3V is a common logic voltage. For 5V the caps should be rated higher than 6V3 to provide a margin.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, but it's impossible to know for sure without a circuit diagram (which will be hard to obtain). The actual capacitance of electrolytics varies quite a lot with temperature so the circuit should work with your 20% value change. It may become unreliable at high temperature or under heavy load.

Comment: Also note that if it's a switching stage cap, it's parasitics are more of a concern.

Comment: @Dzarda, what do you mean by switching cap and associated parasitics?

Comment: @sherrellbc: By that I meant a capacitor that participates closely with the step-down regulation of an onboard voltage. In such a capacitor it's low ESR and ESL values are most desirable.